# Using the_title() function doesn't show in loop

Tags: wordpress

I don't know if I'm being sill here but I have an issue with Wordpress' WP_Query. I have the following code:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query();
$the_query->query('post_type=property');

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="featured">
        <h1><?php the_title()  ?>d</h1>
        <!--<ul>
            <li>3 Bedrooms</li>
            <li>Large Garden</li>
            <li>Walking distance to shops</li>
            <li>Semi-Detached</li>                                
        </ul>-->
        <a href="#" class="more-info">More details</a>
    </div>

    <?php
endwhile;
```

It correctly finds 3 posts, however it doesnt show `the_title()`. Can anyone see a reason why?

Comment: any reason you have the 'd' after the closing php tag ?>d ?

Comment: try following code.. see what appear "global $post; print_r($post);" do you see the correct post with title properly filled up?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `**<?php the_title(); ?>**` ? I think you missed the "**;**" :)

Answer (score 0):

Like *the Hun* said, you simply forgot the **;**

Have a look here if you look for more ressources on [Wp Title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)